# Create customer using XTRF REST API

Tags: xtrf

I want to create customer using XTRF REST API. Please help. I have cross checked the XTRF REST API regarding create customer method. But I haven't found in the API documentation. Is there any other process for creating the customer.

-Vamsi

Answer (score 0):

At present, XTRF doesn't support creating customers via REST API. However, XTRF offers also [WebService API](http://knowledgebase.xtrf.eu/display/XTRFAPIWS), which implements [createCustomer function](http://knowledgebase.xtrf.eu/display/XTRFAPIWS/Methods#Methods-createCustomer). You can see how to use it in [Usage Examples](http://knowledgebase.xtrf.eu/display/XTRFAPIWS/Usage+Examples) section of the documentation.

Note that XTRF REST API is available only for the customers who have purchased access to it, while XTRF [WebService API](http://knowledgebase.xtrf.eu/display/XTRFAPIWS) is publicly available for all XTRF customers.

Comment: Hi Pastuszko Thanks for the reply. I have integrated XTRF REST API with my application. Can we use both webservice API and REST API in single application where it is necessary.

Comment: Sure, you can use both APIs in a single application. They are both under active development (especially REST API), so expect their functionality to extend in the near future.